# Creating a custom jQuery countdown table

Tags: jquery, html

I'm not asking for someone to code this for me, I just want a bit of advice and guidance.

Basically, I started learning jQuery last week and for my first project I want to make a countdown table.
e.g.

```
=====================
Time|Desc
---------------------
1.03|Item 1
---------------------
0.50|Item 2
=====================
```

Once the user starts the countdown the first item should be retrieved and used as a countdown, ie 1.03,1.02,1.01,1,0.59 in seconds (and should be updated live). Once that reaches zero, the row should be removed and the next item should be started as a countdown.

If anyone has had any experience building this or a countdown similar to this I would appreciate it. I've seen a few plugins but it seems overkill for my needs. All times will be less than an hour.

A few things; I'm struggling to understand is how I could initialize the second countdown as obviously the first row will take a few seconds to animate or remove.

Any feedback, links, reading is appreciated I'm currently learning using a video course and will be finished in the next few days, but this is something outside of the class that I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Preview](http://jsbin.com/etogi) and
[Source](http://jsbin.com/etogi/edit)

```
var position = 0;
var countdowns = $(".time");

var interval = setInterval( function()
{
  if (countdowns [position].innerHTML == 0)
  {
    $(countdowns [position]).parent().hide();
    position ++;
  }
  if (position >= countdowns.length)
  {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  else
  {
    countdowns[position].innerHTML --;
  }

},1000);
```

Comment: That's great! I'm going to go over it and try make head and tales of it. Looks like exactly what I was going to implement, just in a much quicker way!

Comment: Had a chance to look over it, works perfect. I've adapted it for my own uses, for times in minutes this script will have to be adapted if anyone else is using it.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have some time ago helped out making a jQuery timer. The functionality is as a stop watch  instead of doing a countdown (I'm using it for a timetracker web app). You might find that helpful, since you possible only need to change a few things to make it into what you need. I have it on [Github](http://github.com/googletorp/jquery.timeclock.js) which is a bit flaky these days with the recent server move. You can take a look at this and just use it as inspiration if you want to implement this yourself from the ground up.